# external sql query in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have trouble with this code in cakephp for a sql query

Here my code in RankingsController.php

```
<?php
class RankingsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');


    public function index() {

    $this->Ranking->virtualFields += array(
    'totalpoints' => 0);    

    $rankings = $this->Ranking->query("
    select turnierranks.teilnehmer_id as teilnehmer_id, 
    teilnehmers.nachname, teilnehmers.vorname,
    sum(pointtab.points) as totalpoints
    from turnierranks, pointtab, turniers, teilnehmers 
    where 
    turnierranks.turnier_id = turniers.id and
    turniers.turnierkategorie = pointtab.kategorie and
    turnierranks.rank     = pointtab.rank and
    teilnehmers.id = teilnehmer_id
    group by teilnehmer_id, teilnehmers.nachname, teilnehmers.nachname
    order by totalpoints desc");

      debug($rankings); 

    }
 }
```

debug (rankings$) show the right querydata

but in views/Rankings/index.cpt i get the error

Undefined variable: rankings [APP/View/Rankings/index.ctp, line 12]
and the same error for the next line

```
 LINE 12: <?php   debug($rankings); ?>


<?php foreach ($rankings as $ranking): ?>
```

in Model ranking.php

```
<?php
class Ranking extends AppModel {
 public $useTable = false; 
}
```

whats is wrong with the $rankings variable array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass a variable from your controller to the View, you need to set a `viewVar`;

In your example:

```
$rankings = ..........


$this->set('rankings', $rankings);
```

The first parameter is the name of the viewVar to create/set, for example:

```
$this->set('FooBar', $rankings);
```

Would create a viewVar 'FooBar' containing the content of $rankings that will be  available inside your View via a variable `$FooBar`

See this chapter in the documentation [Interacting with Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#interacting-with-views)

### Custom queries / raw SQL

This is not part of your question, however, you seem to be writing your own SQL statements to retrieve your data. Not only does this allow potential SQL vulnerabilities in your code, you also *skip* most functionality of the CakePHP Models.

Using CakePHP models the 'right' way, will reduce the amount of code required, and will properly protect you agains SQL injections etc.

Please read the chapter on Models in the documentation;

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html#models

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: thank you, it works - I work only for 2 days with cakephp and I must say it is A lovely work frame. I have previously in assembler (8080) dBase, Clipper, C, sybase PowerBuilder, and programmed coldfusion

Comment: If this is a new project and you are able to change the database schema, it's well worth the time to name your tables and fields according to the [CakePHP conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html). When following the conventions, CakePHP will automatically 'discover' the right columns to use for building relations between database tables. This will save you a lot of headaches and configuration/settings

Comment: On a side note; Controllers will automatically 'inherit' Helpers and Components that are set in the AppController, so you don't have to configure them in each controller, just specify Components that are *not* set in the AppController. Since CakePHP 2.3, most Helpers don't have to be specified *at all*, CakePHP uses AutoLoading to load them if required, a real time saver. I hope my information was useful. Please mark your question 'answered' by accepting my answer.